# vb.net to c# code conversion

Tags: c#, vb.net

what would be its c# equivalent code

```
    Dim arLines() As String
Dim int i
    arLines = Split(RTB1.Text, vbNewLine)
    For i = 0 To UBound(arLines)
        ''# RTB2.Text = arLines(i)
    Next i
```

Comment: i tried online tools also to convert that code to c# but it didn't work....

Comment: Your code is really simple. If you know what it does and a little bit C#, you should be able to translate it yourself without any tool. What part do you need help with?

Comment: Who upvoted something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string[] arLines;
arLines = RTB1.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
for( int i = 0; i < arLines.Length; ++i )
{
    RTB2.Text = arLines[i];
}
```

That's done, but your code just wipes out the Text property of RTB2 each iteration (I'm assuming it is not supposed to be commented out as it is in your example), so you may as well just do this:

```
string[] arLines;
arLines = RTB1.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
RTB2.Text = arLines[arLines.Length-1];
```

Comment: Crazy stuff.  arLines[arLines.Length] is a guaranteed IndexOutOfRangeException.  The last valid index is arLines.Length - 1.  What is everybody smoking today?

Comment: Environment.NewLine is not always the same as vbNewLine. It is "\n" on Unix platforms and "\r\n" on other platforms. vbNewLine always is "\r\n". So you better use Constants.vbNewLine from Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll.

Answer (score 4):

The reason the online tools didn't help you was because you weren't sending valid VB in the first place.

```
Dim int i ''# will not compile
```

You need

```
Dim i As Integer ''# This will compile
```

Here's the C# equivalent

```
string arLines = null;
int i = 0;
arLines = Strings.Split(RTB1.Text, Constants.vbNewLine);
for (i = 0; i <= Information.UBound(arLines); i++) {
 RTB2.Text = arLines(i);
}
```

However, the code above (a direct VB to C# translation) isn't going to be much help for you either since RTB2.Text will simply be the LAST iteration of your for loop.

A great translation tool is found at
http://converter.telerik.com

Comment: BTW, at least in my Code for the library call "Constants.vbNewLine" to work I had to explicitly include a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic in the project references.

Comment: That's right @Jeff. The OP would have been better off doing a manual translation.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good translator at Developer Fusion -  http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

I've tried translating your code but the translator only works if your code compiles to start with (this is always an excellent place to start!).  See suggestion from @rockinthesixstring :)

Comment: @Hans can you elaborate? I've always found it pretty reliable - it has saved me from manually converting many pages of VB code (I'm capable of doing it but who wants to spend that time?).

Comment: Information.UBound?  How can a converter not know that an array has a Length property?